# Progressbar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Could someone help me fix the progressbar count?
It's only counting until 51% even I count the source items already
Could you tell me what's the problem with the codes? I just modified it with the existing codes here from C#

```
  Dim counter As Double = 1
    Dim outputFolder As String = txtFileOutput.Text + "\" + txtFileName.Text + ".ts"
    Dim encryptionKey As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(txtKeyFile.Text)
    Dim inputFilestream As FileStream
    Dim outputFilestream As FileStream
    Try
        outputFilestream = New FileStream(outputFolder, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, FileOptions.SequentialScan)

        For Each obj2 As Object In ListView1.Items
            Dim sourceitem2 As SourceItem = CType(obj2, SourceItem)

            Dim encryptionIV As Byte() = New Byte(15) {}

            inputFilestream = New FileStream(sourceitem2.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan)

            Dim aes As New AesManaged With {
                .Key = encryptionKey,
                .IV = encryptionIV,
                .Mode = CipherMode.CBC
            }

            Dim encryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor()
            Dim cryptoStream = New CryptoStream(inputFilestream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

            Dim count = sourceitem2.FileName.Length

            'PROGRESSBAR
            Dim value As Double = (counter / sourceitem2.FileName.Length) * 100
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(value))

            cryptoStream.CopyTo(outputFilestream)

            counter += 1

            inputFilestream.Close()
        Next
        outputFilestream.Flush()
        outputFilestream.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You appear to be looping through ListView1.Items, but comparing a position in that loop against the length of each filename.  Not sure that's what you are really trying to do, so maybe try Dim value As Double = (counter / ListView1.Items.Count) * 100 instead.

Comment: I'll try it thank you. I'll give a feedback

Comment: It worked 100% :) thank you so much

What I'm trying to do is show progressbar when the decrypt process started
I'm really newbie in progressbar that's why really don't know how to use properly

Comment: But the problem, I tried with and without progressbar.
If progressbar enabled it takes about 3minutes to finish the process and without progressbar only a seconds.
Could you help me?

Comment: Remove each and every reference to UI Controls from the `DoWork` handler of a BackgroundWorker. Pass the **values** of UI elements through the [RunWorkerAsync(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync) overload. This include the `BackgroundWorker1` object reference, since you used the Component instead of creating the object when needed. Use `dim bgWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)` instead.

Comment: You should also show the ReportProgress handler.

Comment: Hello Jim do you mind if you could give me sample about DirectCast? although there's google but your suggestion might help

Comment: I think I can understand now what you mean.
I should not do a lot of task iniside the DoWork. so I will update it tomorrow and I will put some task inside the ProgressChange

Thank you for the information

Comment: About `DirectCast`: that's all there is, it's just a function call. About the rest: nope, the heavy-lifting code goes to the DoWork event. The point is, this event is raised in a Thread other than the UI thread, so you cannot reference UI element in there. If you need to access an UI element, then do it when all the data needed to report progress has been elaborated and you raise the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: Yeah I did a research again earlier to understand background workers.
But I still can't find a way how to speed up the process while using filestream

Comment: Just a side note, streams need to be closed and disposed. Try Using blocks.

Comment: Hi guys I tried to make some changes in my code and with the help of suggestion by Jon, Jimi and Mary.
But I don't see any progress of the process. I mean still slow the processing while decrypting files. Could you suggest more changes to speed up the process?

Here's the updated code
https://pastebin.com/hdnWq3k1